# Labeling points in gnuplot data series

Tags: label, gnuplot

I have been reading a post already written on this subject, but I can not represent my data since an error appears.

%data.txt:

```
"Hf" 2233 13.31
"Ir" 2466 22.56
"B_4C" 2763 2.52
"Y_2O_3" 2425 5.03
"Nb" 2477 8.57
"NbN" 2573 8.47
"SrZrO_3" 2700 5.1
"SiC" 2830 3.16
"ZrO_2" 2715 5.68
"Mo" 2623 10.28
"VC" 2810 5.77
"TiB_2" 3230 4.52
"HfO_2" 2758 9.68
"UO_2" 2867 10.97
"TiN" 2930 5.22
"TiC" 3160 4.93
"ZrB_2" 3246 6.085
"ZrN" 2952 7.09
"TaB_2" 3140 11.15
"C" 3549 2.27
"ZrC" 3540 6.73
"ThO_2" 3390 10
"HfB_2" 3250 10.5
"HfN" 3305 13.8
"NbC" 3608 7.82
"Re" 3186 21.02
"W" 3422 19.25
"Ta" 3017 16.65
"WC" 2830 15.63
"TaC" 3880 14.6
"HfC" 3890 12.2
```

%code:

```
set terminal postscript enhanced color"Times-Roman" 20
set output "TemperatureVsDensity.eps"
set xlabel "Temperature [degrees]}"
set ylabel " Density  [g/cc]"

plot "data.txt" using 2:3 , "" u 2:3:1 w labels rotate offset 1
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: what is the error message? Maybe gnuplot wants to tell you that you should remove the `}` at the end of `set xlabel "Temperature [degrees]}"`?

Comment: and in the same line at the time of putting the point in black, for some reason, when I use the same method you have indicated, nothing appears on the graph. `plot "data.txt" u 2:3 w p pt 7 lc rgb "black" notitle, '' u 2:3:1 w labels left offset 1,0 notitle`

Comment: put `reset session` at the beginning of your code. It resets previous settings (e.g. limited ranges) which could cause unexpected results (e.g. empty graphs).

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you can post the error message you got when trying to run your code. I copied your data, code, and ran `gnuplot code` on the terminal. `gnuplot` gives the following warning (not error):

> "code", line 6: warning: enhanced text mode parser - ignoring spurious }

which tells you that you should remove the spurious `}` on your `set ylabel` statement (as pointed out in the comments already). However, that does not prevent the figure to be generated. This is what I got:

[image: output]